# Docker persistent volume

Tags: ubuntu, docker

> To deal with data going away once the container is shut,

I'm trying to implement a command to mount a persistent volume.
That way, people can swap the containers(for upgrades, etc) aggressively without fearing loss of data.

```
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~/apache2-Docker# docker run -it -d -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -P --name mavenLOG -v /root/apache2-Docker/mavenLOG/:/var/log maven-apache2-test02 
27125546z622992f301788c49ab99279cfe71e30a399b26bbc8a5c83050cd56c
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~/apache2-Docker#
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~/apache2-Docker# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
27125546z622        maven-apache2-test02            "/usr/bin/supervisord"   16 seconds ago      Exited (2) 16 seconds ago                            mavenLOG
```

> Want:

(1) Host has this folder

```
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~/apache2-Docker# ls 
all-in-one  mavenLOG
```

(2) Container has `/var/log` going on and writes when apps start

(3) I want to new containers to respect the data already present and NOT overwrite or replace but read and write from then on

(4) We have existing ports being used that I used to spawn with "`docker run -it -d -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 maven-apache2-test02`" BEFORE the persistent command

But container keeps on dying.
What am I doing wrong here?

Is simply volume/folder mapping not allowed in Docker? 
I don't need to mount any new volumes on the container.

[Update:]

```
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~# docker logs 27125546z622
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
```

But this solved it,

```
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~/apache2-Docker/apache2-maven# docker run -it -d -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 -P --name mavenLOG -v /root/apache2-Docker/mavenLOG/:/var/log maven-apache2-test02 /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
06eff95ea56bfe5333e5b7bc0420530fb879bd922ff13b11435e19fac734eb31
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~/apache2-Docker/apache2-maven# 
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~/apache2-Docker/apache2-maven# 
root@docker-ubuntu-9:~/apache2-Docker/apache2-maven# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
06eff95ea56b        maven-apache2-test02            "/usr/bin/supervisord"   4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   mavenLOG
```

> So now my "log" will be populated with container's "/var/log"?

Comment: could you post the Dockerfile and the log of the dead container (docker log 27125546z622)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (3) I want to new containers to respect the data already present and
>   NOT overwrite or replace but read and write from then on

As mentioned by [@Mario,](https://serverfault.com/users/15039/mario) this depends on the "maven-apache2-test02" container. 
However, this is do-able. 
I quickly created a setup, take a look [here.](https://github.com/maniankara/serverfault/tree/master/docker/concurrent-persistant-volume)

As you can see from the demo that, two different containers can write to same file from the host concurrently respecting the already exiting data